# MySQL Keeps shutting down

Tags: mysql, linux, server

I am having an issue regarding my MySQL Database.

I have a program which has a mild to heavy traffic per day. It was working well before but these past few days it keeps on shutting and the server restarts it after a few seconds or worst I have to restart it manually. What I don't understand is that how and why does it keeps on shutting down. It displays this notes on MySQL logs :

```
2020-01-28T06:02:00.157339Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2020-01-28T06:02:00.157379Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2020-01-28T06:02:00.157385Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2020-01-28T06:02:00.157393Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2020-01-28T06:02:00.157442Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162900Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162903Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162906Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162910Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162913Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162916Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162920Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162923Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162927Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162930Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162933Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162937Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162940Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162943Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162947Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162950Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162954Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162957Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162960Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162964Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162967Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.162970Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2020-01-28T06:02:00.163030Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-01-28T06:02:00.163125Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-01-28T06:02:00.263407Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-01-28T06:02:00.264206Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200128  6:02:00
2020-01-28T06:02:01.380815Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 564620850
2020-01-28T06:02:01.382628Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-01-28T06:02:01.382643Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2020-01-28T06:02:01.382649Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-01-28T06:02:01.382654Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2020-01-28T06:02:01.382657Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2020-01-28T06:02:01.382833Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2020-01-28T06:02:01.383206Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

**GLOBAL STATUS**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S9kTDaMlNMenWMbGg_mByHQnG-eYRYap/view

**GLOBAL VARIABLE**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Inqp8xv3NYmEJY9x8_QmasNCp4VZUCbF/view

**ADDED INFORMATION**

**Memory as of now:** ***563M/15.7G***

**Description:**    ***Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS***

**MySQL Server version:** ***5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)***

I have tried searching around the web but unfortunately didn't find a solution. I hope someone can help me with this. If I am missing out some information that may help in resolving this, just let me know. Thank you

Comment: Just a guest, but if you see no errors in the logs, then this looks like a controlled shutdown, so there ought to be a script doing `service stop mysql` or maybe even someone running [shutdown](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/shutdown.html) sql command.

Comment: @MartinWickman Thank you, I was having the same problem as OP and your answer saved me, I had a cron job checking the status of mysql server (for over a year without issues) and it would restart the service if it wasn't running, but for some reason it stopped working correctly and was restarting mysql every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Please send **SHOW GLOBAL STATUS** and **SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES** values.

Comment: I have updated my question. I added the two links that redirects to SHOW GLOBAL STATUS and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES